# Class reset the variable

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub, dart-html

I have a class like this

```
class UserInfo {
  String userName;
  String userAddress;
  String userCity;
  int userPhone;
}
```

Inside the application I am using the class like this

```
UserInfo user;
user.userName = "Mani";
user.userAddress = "No12, XYZ Street";
user.userCity = "WorldCity";
user.userPhone = 1234567;
```

When I set the values it is working fine. In the middle of the application, I want to change the phone value alone from 1234567 to 5555555 (rest of the values are all same) in different module.

I tried to change like this

```
UserInfo user;
user.userPhone = 5555555;
```

It is giving error, can anyone tell me how to do this correctly.

Comment: Please add the error.

Answer (score 2):

If you really do call this code:

```
UserInfo user;
user.userPhone = 5555555;
```

it means you're redeclaring a variable called `user` but not instantiating anything. And therefore, you're most likely getting a Null Pointer Exception trying to change the value of `userPhone`.

Comment: Thanks I will check it and come back

Answer (score 1):

```
UserInfo user;
```

only declares a variable. This variable doesn't yet reference a value.

It should be

```
UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
```

If you later use on another location

```
UserInfo user;
user.userPhone = 5555555;
```

you declare a different `user` instance that is again not initialized with a concrete value.

If you want to reuse the first `user` variable, you need to import the library (file) that contains it.

Comment: If I UserInfo user = new UserInfo(); the old values will also get changed, I don't want that to happen, I want the old values but I want to change only the phone value

Comment: I will check your solution and come back